# C++ Declaring many similar classes without repeating oneself

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, declaration

I would like to know a smart way to avoid repeating myself in the following declaration of similar structs. All the structs in the code below inherit publicly from boost::spirit::qi::symbols, where EnumType is different for each struct.

```
struct website_ : qi::symbols<char, Website>
{
  website_() : qi::symbols<char, Website>(website_names, Website_values) { }
} website_;

struct currency_name_ : qi::symbols<char, Currency>
{
  currency_name_ () : qi::symbols<char, Currency>(currency_names, Currency_values) { }
} currency_name_;
```

Where, for example

```
 enum Website { /*list of websites*/ };
 const std::vector<Website> Website_values = { /*same list as above*/ };
 const std::vector<std::string> website_names = { /* list of corresponding names of websites*/ };
```

The goal is to initialize every struct giving only the appropriate enum, vector of enum values and vector of strings with the names of the values.

I have thought of a solution with a new subclass of qi::symbols, from which all of my structs would inherit but I think it might be an overkill, and another perhaps using macros (which I am not very familiar with). Is there another method using some other kind of metaprogramming? Or perhaps some other trick from the Boost Library, which I am already using anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why templates were invented.

```
template<EnumType t>
struct symbol_type: qi::symbols<char, t>
{
  symbol_type(const std::vector<std::string>& names, const std::vector<t>& values) 
  : qi::symbols<char, t>(names, values) { }
};

symbol_type<Website> website(website_names, website_values);
symbol_type<Currency> currency(currency_names, currency_values);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question you can use below code:

```
typedef  qi::symbols<char, Website> website_;
typedef  qi::symbols<char, Currency> currency_name_;
```

Comment: Why does your answer look foolish, when it also takes care of initializing struct qi::symbols with the given values?

Comment: What, like `website_ website(website_names, website_values);`?  Even _that_ is better than mine!